# Form serialization always returns empty string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, serialization

I have a dropdown in my view. Based on the selection, i insert a partial view into a div (placeholder) in view. Below is the View.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4"><p class="lead">What do you want to do?</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <select id="myDropDown">
            <option id="0" selected>I want to..</option>
            <option id="1">Reset my password</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="partialPlaceHolder" style="display:none;"> </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myDropDown').change(function () {

        /* Get the selected value of dropdownlist */
        var selectedID = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('id');

        /* Request the partial view with .get request. */
        $.get('/Requests/FindPartial/' + selectedID, function (data) {

            /* data is the pure html returned from action method, load it to your page */
            $('#partialPlaceHolder').html(data);
            /* little fade in effect */
            $('#partialPlaceHolder').fadeIn('fast');
        });

    });
});
```

So when I select, "Reset my password" in the dropdown, I am successfully inserting my partial view into the div in my view. Below is my partial view.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-12">
             <div class="well well-lg" style="text-align:left">
                 <div class="form-horizontal" id="resetpasswordform">
                     <h4>Reset Password</h4>
                     <hr />
                     <div class="form-group">
                         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ServersList, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                         <div class="col-md-10">
                             @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ServerName, new SelectList(Model.ServersList))
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                         <div class="col-md-10">
                             @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                         <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                             <input type="button" id="submitButton" value="Reset" class="btn btn-default" />
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 }
 <script>
     $(function () {
         $("#submitButton").click(function () {
             debugger;
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "Requests/Do_ResetPassword",
                 data: $("#resetpasswordform").serialize(),
                 success: function (data) {
                     debugger;
                 },
                 error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                 {
                     alert(errorThrown);
                 }
             });
         });
     });
 </script>
```

The problem is when the submit button is clicked, and I make the ajax post call, the `$("#resetpasswordform").serialize()` is always "" (empty string).

I tried making the view just with one element. I verified that the elements have name attribute for serialize to work. I also confirmed that I don't have a `type=submit` in my button. I changed the resetpasswordform into a form instead of div. I even rendered the partial view directly in Index.cshtml without dynamically populating. Nothing fixed the problem. All the time it returns empty string.

I verified all other similar questions in SO and not getting any hint on what i am doing wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you set the id in the form tag:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", FormMethod.Post, new { Id = "resetpasswordform" }))
```

and remove it from the div.

Comment: Yup.... That works!!! Thanks @Qutayba. But how do we explain this? And why should i give action and controller in the htm.BeginForm ? I am only making a jquery call.

Comment: The BeginForm is just a normal method that has some parameters. It's more about the order of the parameters. You can use the "action" attribute of the form in your JS code. $(this).attr('action')